# Not able to autheticate google cloud vision api . How to autheticate it to use it further

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

My Code looks like this :-

```
var vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
handleSubmit = () =>{ 
        console.log("encoded string submitted=",this.state.files);            
        this.useVisionCloud();
    }

    useVisionCloud = () =>{

            const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
            const request_body = {
                "requests": [
                  {
                    "image": {
                      "content": this.state.files
                    },
                    "features": [
                      {
                        "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              };
              client.textDetection(request_body).then(response => {
                    console.log("text got=",response);                    
                  // doThingsWith(response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("error got=",err);   
                });
    }
```

1. I already tried setting environment variable but didn't work .
2. I have also created service account and downloaded the file.json
   **but dont    know how to use it for authentication**

im getting the following error :-

`Uncaught Error: {"clientConfig":{},"port":443,"servicePath":"vision.googleapis.com","scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision"]}You need to pass auth instance to use gRPC-fallback client in browser. Use OAuth2Client from google-auth-library.`

on triggering a post request to Google API .

**Final Query is :- I am not able to understand how to authenticate API so that i can further use it to detect text in my images**

Comment: How did you set the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Set the env variable eg:
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"

I would recommend having a separate backend that calls vision api. Then have the javascript code in your browser call your backend.